Is it not possible to model injective functions using propositional logic?
I'm having some trouble with this question from the 2024 Cambridge Tripos exams:

Let $X, Y$ be infinite sets such that there is an injection from $X$
to $Y$. For each $x ∈ X$, let $A_x$ be a non-empty, finite subset of
$Y$. Let $P$ be a set consisting of pairwise distinct primitive
propositions $p_{x,y}$ for all $x ∈ X$ and $y ∈ Y$. For a valuation
$v$ on $L$, set $$f_v = \{(x, y) ∈ X × Y : v(p_{x,y}) = 1\} .$$
For each of the following statements, either write down a set $S ⊂ L$
that makes the statement true or prove that no such set $S$ exists.
(i) $\{f_v : v$ is a model of $S\}$ is the set of all injective
functions from subsets of $X$ to $Y$.
(ii) $\{f_v : v$ is a model of
$S\}$ is the set of all injective functions $g : X → Y$ such that
$g(x) ∈ A_x$ for all $x ∈ X$.
(iii) $\{f_v : v$ is a model of $S\}$ is the set of all injective
functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Here's where I've got to:
(i) Initially I thought this meant functions $\Bbb P(X) \to Y$, but that didn't make a lot of sense, so I think it's actually $X' \to Y$ where $X'\subseteq X$. $$S=\{p_{x,y}\Rightarrow \lnot p_{x,z}:x\in X,y,z\in Y, y\neq z\}\cup \{p_{x,y}\Rightarrow \lnot p_{z,y}:x,z\in X,y\in Y, x\neq z\}$$
(ii) Because $A_x$ is finite, I think the expressions in the below are ok. $$S= \text{(i)} \cup \left\{ \underset{y\in A_x}\bigvee p_{x,y}:x\in X  \right\} $$
(iii) This is where I get stuck. Having successfully found examples for (i) and (ii), I imagine this is where $S$ does not exist, which seems plausible as it feels as though we would need something like we had in (ii) but with $Y$ replacing $A_x$ but we can't do that because $Y$ is infinite.  Earlier book work in the question was all to do with completeness and compactness, so that's probably relevant, but I'm not sure how. In the first sentence of the stem we are given that if S existed it would have a model, as an injection exists, but I'm not sure where to go from there as existence of the infinite model is usually the conclusion from compactness rather than the premise.
Any help welcome!

I think a good way to look at what's happening here is "first-order/propositional logic cannot express infinite disjunctions". The problem is that you want to assert "$\bigvee_{y \in Y} p_{x,y}$" for each $x$. This is similar to how there's no first-order axiomatisation of finite groups, because what you want to express is then "$\bigvee_{n < \omega} \text{"$G$ has $n$ elements"}$". In both cases, the compactness theorem lets you violate every disjunct to show that there's no such theory.

You're right, this is an application of the compactness theorem.
Suppose $S$ is a propositional theory whose models are exactly the $v$ such that $f_v$ is an injective function $X\to Y$.
Now fix $x\in X$ and consider $S' = S\cup \{\lnot p_{x,y}\mid y\in Y\}$. Show that for any finite subset $\Sigma\subseteq S'$, there is an injective function $f_v$ such that $v$ satisfies $\Sigma$ (we have only prohibited finitely many values of $f_v(x)$). By compactness, there is a valuation $v$ satisfying $S'$. But $f_v$ is not defined on $x$, contradiction.

Thanks I see it now! In hindsight this idea of expanding $S$ until it doesn’t have a model but every finite subset does is something I’ve seen before and should have cottoned on to. I guess the biggest subtlety here is realising from afar that we can tweak the given injection to fit with $\Sigma$ by just swapping a couple of elements. Nice!
